# Regression with a high number of 0's for target variable. How do I approach this?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, predictive-models, model-selection

I have a dataset where the probability of an event happening is very low (15%-20%). When the event happens, there's a dollar amount attached to it. The distribution is very right skewed, ranging from -5,000 to 800,000 with median being 5,000 and mean being 50,000. My first couple models have been horrible (just using GBM and Random Forests) from a predictive stand point.

My initial thought is to do two separate models: Categorical Binary whether or not there is an event, and then a regression on the cost of the event given an event occurs.

Is this the best way of approaching this or are there some algorithms that handle this exact scenario. I'm using R, so any suggestions base around those packages is helpful!

Comment: If the categorical binary has acceptable accuracy, I would use your initial thought method of two models..

Comment: Could a tobit model be an idea?

Comment: For something off the shelf sounds like you might want to try a zero-inflated regression model, like zero-inflated negative binomial regression. The R package pscl has a few options in its zeroinfl function. [Here's](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/zinb/) an example.